# Finding the name of a new pod with kubectl

Tags: kubectl

I am new to k8s and I am running into a little problem here.

Here's the context: 
I need to invoke `kubectl delete [podname]` via a crontask once a day, and wait until k8s recreates the pod, then log into the container in that pod and run a shell command.

So I query the deployment and get something like this:

```
user@host:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
firstpod-123456789-something           1/1       Running   570        2d
secondpod-http-backend-something       1/1       Running   597        2d
```

then I wrote a bash script that would delete the pods in a 5 minutes interval. That's the easy part.

Suppose I invoke `kubectl delete firstpod-123456789-something` and wait for k8s to recreate a new pod. That new pod would have a new name like `firstpod-[some random hash here]-something`

The problem is that I need to capture the name of that pod in my bash script so then I can exec a command in that pod like `uname -a` or whatever as to verify that the new pod is up and running just fine.

I googled it and read the kubectl docs but I don't think there's an easy way to do this via a bash script? I am assuming that the only way to get the pod name here would be via the k8s API?

I am happy to use any solution at this point. I wonder if there's any way that I rename the new pod when k8s spawns up a new one? so I could grep for a specific keyword?

Note that I don't want to egrep something like `firstpod-[0-9]-something` because that's just an example. A lot of pods have a lot of different names, that was just an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to label your `deployment` somehow, for example we set label `app: myapp` below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1                                                                                                                                                                          
kind: Deployment                                                                                                                                                                                        
metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  name: nginx                                                                                                                                                                                     
spec:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  template:                                                                                                                                                                                             
    metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                           
      labels:                                                                                                                                                                                           
        app: my-app                                                                                                                                                                                
    spec:                                                                                                                                                                                               
      containers:                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - image: nginx                                                                                                                                                    
        name: nginx
```

After that you can get deployment's pod name very easy:

```
POD=$(kubectl get pod -l app=my-app -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
```

and execute some command there, for example:

```
kubectl exec -ti $POD -- uname -a
```

Comment: use `-o name` instead of `-o jsonpath=...`

Comment: @Adam Unfortunately this prefixes the result with the type - eg. `pod/mypodname`. Such a shame, as that's SO much easier to remember.

Comment: in my context, this is not helping because I can't label the deployment but that's not due to a technical limitation, it's just a contextual company policy (let's put it that way) so I am going to accept your answer because it sounds like it's the right way to go in purely technical terms.

Comment: So if we have 2 pods and we want to get the name of the LATEST one, how do we do that ? I see `AGE` column but not sure how to use it ..?!?

Comment: don't forget to add your namespace if your pod is in one

Comment: Tested this with `-o name` and `kubectl exec` seems to support the `pod/` prefix now.

Comment: I can confirm that `pod/<podname>` works when supplied to `kubectl exec`. This PowerShell one-liner ended up being what I needed: `kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -o name | Select-String <part of wanted pod name here>) -- /bin/bash`, which runs bash in the found pod.

Answer (score 28):

Like Nickolay wrote, use a label to help selecting.
Then you can use

```
kubectl get pods -l app=my-app -o custom-columns=:metadata.name
```

This gets you the name of the pod that has the label "app=my-app"

Comment: While this may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, is there a way to select the latest pod name only, when the new pod is being deployed?

Comment: I append `--no-headers` to remove header (which becomes empty line if not using it)

Answer (score 4):

Complementing what @nickgryg said, if kubernetes is in the cloud you can add the **namespace** and **kubeconfig** to get the pod name:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=my-app -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}" -n my-namespace --kubeconfig=/home/$USER/.kube/kubeconfig
```

And to delete it with a single command, you can use the following:

```
NAMESPACE=my-namespace APP_NAME=my-app && kubectl delete -n $NAMESPACE pod $(kubectl get pods -l app=$APP_NAME -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}" -n $NAMESPACE --kubeconfig=/home/$USER/.kube/kubeconfig) --kubeconfig=/home/$USER/.kube/kubeconfig
```

Answer (score 4):

All other answers doesnt work for me

Not working option

```
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods  -l app.kubernetes.io/name=nats  -o name
```

working option

```
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods  --selector=app.kubernetes.io/name=nats  -o name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another important/useful point is that you might want just the Running pod; there might be many more in "Terminated" state. Combining useful tips from the comments of others, I get:

```
kubectl get pod -n $NAMESPACE -l app=$PODNAME -o name --field-selector=status.phase=Running
```